# How to achieve the short description about a method in c#?

Tags: c#

In Visual Studio when we write a name of a method and we put the parenthesis and in the parenthesis we press ctrl+shift+space we will see the signature and a description in a small window. how to achieve this signature and description as a string in c#?

Comment: What do you mean by "as a string"? Do you want to write such documentation for your class/methods/fields/etc.?

Comment: Type `///` and autocomplete should kick in and give you a custom template per method signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the method, use the xml tags to be able to lint the descriptions and more

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the answer to a question
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Id"></param>
        /// <param name="Id1"></param>
        /// <param name="Id2"></param>
        /// <param name="answer"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't if I got your question truly. But you can access these XML comments by enabling this ability in your build configuration.
[image]
After you enabled this option and rebuild your project, a file with the name of your project is generated automatically. It is an XML file so you can use link to XML to find comments related to your method.